# How do I get Office 2010 to save in a new file automatically, instead of prompt?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

When I close a document with unsaved changes, Word prompts whether you would like to save the changes, or if you want to not save the changes.

This is usually fine, but not when the system is trying to restart itself from an update, and it forcibly closes word, and the only way to get your document back is to use autorecover.

What I want is for Office programs to, on exit, automatically save open documents with unsaved changes in a NEW file with a NEW name.

I realise this is kind of lazy, but then again... if I was going to be non-lazy I'd write everything by hand :)

Comment: This hasn't been possible in any version of Office.  Why don't you just not save the document before you issue a shutdown?

Comment: Only once has Windows ever did an update and restart without my acceptance. All the other times, it informed me that it needed to restart and allowed me to choose when. You shouldn't have this problem.